# IE Developer Tools - Standard (page default) v/s IE9 Standards?

Tags: internet-explorer, ie-developer-tools, x-ua-compatible

I'm building on a site and test the stuff in IE10. I would like to check backward compatibility with IE Developer Tools, so I switch to `Browsermode: IE9`. Next, I can set `IE9 standards` or `Standard (page default)`, this gives me different results when I load the page.

Do I need to care testing `IE9 standards`, if I set a `DOCTYPE` in the page's `<head>` in my HTML page? Isn't `Standard (page default)` what a user that uses IE9 with standard settings should be able to experience when the page renders?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the most relevant configuration for testing IEs is to set both browser mode and document mode to the same version. That is, in your case, IE 9 and IE 9 standards.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, Jawa, keeping the browser and document modes the same is the way to check (approximately) how IE will render for past versions. I think `Standard (page default)` is meaning `IE10 standards` in this case, so using that instead of the `IE9 standards` when you are in `browser mode IE9` would definitely cause a different render.

The only reason I am aware of to have a different document mode from the browser mode is if you are setting it that way on purpose and designing for it. This old blog post is decent background:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/10/19/testing-sites-with-browser-mode-vs-doc-mode.aspx